# android ontouch on listener on layout wont fire when clicked on a child element

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I am setting an onTouchListener on a linear layout and on touch of the layout user can drag the layout around the screen and reposition the layout. This works fine, but now i have some ImageViews inside the layout and when a user does onTouch on the imageviews the onTouch on the layout does not fire. It fires only when the user clicks anywhere where there are not child elements. I want to be able to drag the layout around no matter where the user clicks within the layout.
Here is some code,

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:id="@+id/layout_panel"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_screenshot_12"></ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_content_cut_12"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:tooltipText="Scissor">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_aspect_ratio_12"
        android:id="@+id/img3">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code behind

```
 layout_panel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private int lastAction;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                             // does code to update the position of the layout.
                             // but this does not fire on click of any imageview 
                             // insdie the layout.
```

I have looked at the onInterceptTouchEvent but unable to figure out how to use it correctly.

Basically i should be able to drag the layout by firing the onTouch on touch of anywhere inside the layout and not just at parts of the layout which are free from any child element. How can I achieve this without disturbing the onclick events of the imageviews?

Hope my requirement is clear.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When you want the parent to intercept the touches even when any of the children is clicked, what you do is that you disable the child to intercept the touches by setting `clickable` as `false` as:

`android:clickable="false"`

By setting this, touch events are passed to the immediate parent.

Comment: But I have click events added to the children as well. This will prevent the click event on the child from being trigerred.

Comment: I tried making the clickable="false" on the child elements, it still made no difference and the child Imageview clicks are firing as they were before!